# -(void) drawRect:(CGRect)rect; is using up nearly all of iPhone CPU

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-animation, core-graphics

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect{

    float sliceSize = rect.size.width / imagesShownAtOnce;
    //Apply our clipping region and fill it with black
    [clippingRegion addClip];
    [clippingRegion fill];

    //Draw the 3 images (+1 for inbetween), with our scroll amount.
    CGPoint loc;
    for (int i=0;i<imagesShownAtOnce+1;i++){
        loc = CGPointMake(rect.origin.x+(i*sliceSize)-imageScroll, rect.origin.y);
        [[buttonImages objectAtIndex:i] drawAtPoint:loc];
    }

    //Draw the text region background
    [[UIColor blackColor] setFill];
    [textRegion fillWithBlendMode:kCGBlendModeNormal alpha:0.4f];

     //Draw the actual text.
    CGRect textRectangle = CGRectMake(rect.origin.x+16,rect.origin.y+rect.size.height*4/5.6,rect.size.width/1.5,rect.size.height/3);
    [[UIColor whiteColor] setFill];
    [buttonText drawInRect:textRectangle withFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Avenir-HeavyOblique" size:22]];
}
```

`clippingRegion` and `textRegion` are `UIBezierPaths` to give me the rounded rectangles I want (First for a clipping region, 2nd as an overlay for my text)

The middle section is drawing 3 images and letting them scroll along, which im updating every 2 refreshes from a `CADisplayLink`, and that invalidates the draw region by calling `[self setNeedsDisplay]`, and also increasing my imageScroll variable.

---

Now that that background information is done, here is my issue:

It runs, and even runs smoothly. But it is using up an absolutely high amount of CPU time (80%+)!! How do I push this off to the GPU on the phone instead? Someone told me about CALayers but I've never dealt with them before

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Draw each component of your drawing once into something (a view or layer) and let it hold the cached the drawing. Then you just move or transform each component, and exactly as you say, it's all done by the GPU.

You could do this with individual views or with individual layers, but that doesn't really matter (a view *is* a layer, under the hood). The point is that there is no need to be constantly redrawing from scratch when all you really want is to move the same persistent pieces around.

Learning about CALayer would be a good idea, as it is in fact the basis of all drawing on iOS. What could be more important to know about than that?

Comment: I'll try to implement this today! I didn't know CALayers acted like it was already drawn in the GPU space and thought this would be futile as I'd need to refresh everything every frame... but thanks!

Comment: Not just CALayers but UIViews as well, since a UIView *is* a CALayer (or a collection of CALayers). Views contain no drawing of their own; they are just touchable wrappers for layers. The whole point - indeed, the genius - of the iOS drawing system is that once you've drawn into a view (i.e. layer) the drawing is cached and is never redrawn unless explicitly told to do so. It is cheap to move an existing drawing, stretch it, transform it, change its opacity, etc.

Comment: Also, if you're animating, why not use UIView animation or CAAnimation? They are cheap too. You should not be redrawing every frame, yourself. Or, if you're writing a game with sprites, use OpenGL.

Comment: @RyanCopley: For the two fills, you'll find CAShapeLayer relevant. http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CAShapeLayer_class/